# Smoke simulation acting strange (2.81a)

Tags: smoke-simulation

I was playing around with smoke simulations and saw that something was wrong. I've narrowed it down to a very simple setup. It simply involves applying the "Quick Smoke" option to the default cube. As you can see, the smoke is starting offset from the supposed emitter.

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on? I've tried restarting blender and I've also tried in 2.82 (with mantaflow) but I have the same problem.

Comment: Have you re-baked the file, it seems like youve moved the domain without rebaking it

Comment: I used quick smoke on the default cube, no baking was involved (unless quick smoke bakes it under the hood). What you see is in viewport mode.